# Reference Counting with Instruments

Tags: cocoa, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I put the code below in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, and launched the app via *Instruments*, in conjunction with the *Allocations* tool.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    var a = Apartment()
    var b = a
    var c = a
    var d = a
}
```

Apple's documentation on memory management in Swift includes the following line:

> Whenever you assign a class instance to a property, constant, or variable, that property, constant, or variable makes a strong reference to the instance...

I was under the impression that a strong reference to an object would up that object's reference count by one. By having four variables storing a reference to the same `Apartment` object I further assumed that at some point *Instruments* would show this object with a reference count of four. But it never does. Instead, the reference count peaks at one - as if the references stored by `b`, `c` and `d` weren't counted. Why is this?

Comment: You would have to look at the generated code, but any decent compiler will eliminate all of those variables as ultimately unused.

Comment: Did you activate the "Record Reference Counts" option in Instruments?

Comment: Yes, I made sure "Record Reference Counts" was checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clang compiler is quite clever to remove unnecessary retain/release
calls. In this case, the variables `b, c, d` have the same lifetime
as `a`, therefore additional increments of the reference count are not necessary.

If you make `a, b, c, d` (optional) properties:

```
var a, b, c, d : Apartment?
```

of your class and change the code to

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    a = Apartment()
    b = a
    c = a
    d = a
    return true
}
```

then you'll observe multiple retain/release calls in Instruments,
with a final count of 4.

This again shows that one never can rely on the retain count having
any certain value.

Comment: I think I'd  come across a post somewhere suggesting that the retain count reported by *Instruments* would only ever be bigger than expected - this was clearly misleading.